# JavaScript variable and the same variable also be an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, object

I am somewhat new to JavaScript and I have a question.

I know you can set variables and "sub-variables". Like:

```
var msg = "Hello World";
alert(msg);
```

and also

```
var msg = {
    lipsum: "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet"
}
alert(msg.lipsum);
```

But I was wondering if you could do *both*, like

```
var msg = "Hello World" || {
    lipsum: "Lorem Ipsum"
}
alert(msg + msg.lipsum);
```

That way, you can declare a variable and also have the same variable be an object. Obviously it couldn't be done with what I did, but you get the picture.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually, you can.

```
var msg = {
    lipsum: "Lorem Ipsum",
    toString: function() {return "Hello World!"}
};
```

Comment: Really? And I wouldn't have to do `alert(msg.toString())`?

Comment: Nope, because `alert` expects a string so it will attempt to convert whatever you give it to one, by calling its `toString` method.

Comment: I would note that you're _really_ not keeping the same mentality when you're doing this. You're just making an object (still) and overriding how it gets cast as a string. Does it work? Absolutely. Just it's no longer a simple string. And if you were trying to use `var foo = msg + 10;` you'll have a hard time getting `msg` as a number.

Comment: +1.. Excellent solution  .. @ModernDesigner.. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/eZSAV/

Comment: Cool!! Thank you! That's what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 12):

JavaScript variables can contain either objects or primitives. If you have an object, you can set properties on it (sub-variables), if you have a primitive, you can't.

Back to your example, [JavaScript Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) can be either a primitive or an object, depending on how you define it, and to make matters more confusing, a primitive will be temporarily converted to an object when you try to access its properties.

The following code will display "bar", as our string is specifically declared as a String object with the `new` keyword:

```
a = new String("Hello World");
a.foo = "bar";
alert(a.foo);
```

If we remove the `new String` part, we get a primitive instead. JavaScript converts it for us when we try to set `foo`, but nothing gets saved, as it's really just a primitive underneath, and we get back the result "undefined" when we call `alert(b.foo)`:

```
b = "Hello World";
b.foo = "bar";
alert(b.foo);
```

This is just one of many things that are confusing about the built-in JavaScript types, I recommend reading through the [Mozilla Javascript Reference's Global Objects section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference#Global_Objects) for all the gory details.

Answer (score 6):

Kolink is absolutely correct in that as long as you expect the value to be a string then you can "box" the value in an object then override the [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method. But, all that does is **allow javascript (*when it needs to output the object as a string*) to output the variable** (by natively calling `toString` for you). It's not returning the original value, but a value boxed in another object.

I'd like to point out a couple things to make it known how the two can vary (with a few examples). So, let's take the following piece:

```
var BoxedString = {
  value: 'Hello, world!',
  toString: function(){ return this.value; }
};
var BoxedNumber = {
  value: 3.14,
  toString: function(){ return this.value; }
};
var BoxedDate = {
  value: new Date(), // today
  toString: function(){ return this.value; }
};
```

Simple, we can output each of these as strings when necessary (or can we?)

```
// Each of these implicitly calls `.toString()` because we're concatenating
// them within another string. Metho calls (like `alert()` that look for a 
// string result have the same effect.
console.log('BoxedString: '+BoxedString); // BoxedString: Hello, world!
console.log('BoxedNumber: '+BoxedNumber); // BoxedNumber: 3.14
console.log('BoxedDate:   '+BoxedDate);   // fail!
```

Wait, `BoxedDate` failed; Why is that? Because our `toString` is returning the `Date` object back and that can't be output as-is. However, if we change the `BoxedDate.toString` to return `this.value.toString()` we'll see better results (go ahead and try it, I'll wait.)

Let's stick with the `BoxedDate` trend and try a date method:

```
console.log(BoxedDate.getFullYear()); // BoxedDate.getFullYear is not a function
```

Once again, it's not actually a `Date`, it's a `Date` wrapped in a shiny box. Oddly enough Javascript knows enough to implicitly cast `BoxedNumber`:

```
var sum = 38.86 + BoxedNumber; // 42 (works)
```

However, don't attempt any `Number` object methods such as `toFixed()`. Same things with `BoxedString` and string methods like `.replace()`, `toUpperCase()` and others.

If I was going to add something to @Kolink's answer, though, it would be to also include [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) as part of the object declaration. Something like:

```
var BoxedValue = {
  value: 2013,
  toString: function(){ return this.value.toString(); }
  valueOf: function(){ return this.value; }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by creating a new object and extending the prototype `toString()` method. Something like that should work:

```
function Msg() {
    this.message = 'some message';
    this.lipsum = 'lipsum';
}

Msg.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.message;
}

var msg = new Msg();

alert(msg + msg.lipsum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually `"Hello World"` is a *string literal* (`typeof "Hello World" === "string"`), not instanceof anything.

You could create a

```
var s = new String("Hello World");
```

and that's now `typeof s === "object"`, `instanceof String` and `Object`.

The String Object can also have additional properties, like

```
s.hint = "!";
// console.log(s + s.hint) prints "Hello World!" into console
```

What you actually need is most likely what the others answered ;)

Answer (score 1):

As long as your variable is not a [primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Declaring_types) you can add properties to it.

In your case

```
var msg = "Hello World";
```

`msg` is a primitive variable, so you can't achieve what you want.
But you can create a real `String object` and add it properties.

```
var msg = new String("Hello World");
msg.lipsum = "lipsum";
alert(msg + msg.lipsum);
```