# Make toPrimitive conversion depend on the context

Tags: javascript, types

I want an object to return one value in a numeric context and a completely different one in a string context. The following doesn't work.

```
foo = {
    toString: function() { return "string" },
    valueOf:  function() { return 123 }
}

console.log(foo * 2)       // got 246, fine
console.log("hi " + foo)   // got "hi 123", want "hi string"
```

Comment: actually the answers to the other question pretty much do explain both _why_, and also why there's no _how_.  The only work arounds appear to be to write `console.log("hi " + String(foo))` or use `foo.toString()`

Comment: Have a look at [this question too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330084/javascript-variable-and-the-same-variable-also-be-an-object). It's along the same lines in terms of object referencing as specific types.

Comment: @Alnitak: alas, it seems you're right and there's no other way. Since the other question doesn't mention workarounds, could you convert your comment to an answer for other's reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [addition operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition) will convert both operands to primitives using the internal abstract operation [`ToPrimitive`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive), and then, if one operand is a string, it will use the internal abstract operation [`ToString`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tostring) to convert both to strings (note: this is different from the `toString` method on userland objects.)

The upshot is, that with addition of [`Symbol.toPrimitive`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive) to the language, you can now achieve your goal:

```js
const foo = {
  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
    switch (hint) {
      case "string":
      case "default":
        return "string"
      case "number":
        return 123
      default:
        throw "invalid hint"
    }
  }
}

console.log(foo * 2) // 246
console.log("hi " + foo) // "hi string"
```